# Why do luggage carts cost money to use in U.S. airports, but are provided free of charge in other places?

Tags: usa, luggage, airports

I noticed that in U.S. airports, there is a charge of around $5 to use the luggage carts. Generally, the only place I see them free are in international arrivals; in departures and domestic arrivals, one has to pay. (After searching this site a little bit, this also appears to be the case for Canada.)

However, in many other airports, usually outside the U.S., luggage carts are provided free of charge, in all airport zones.

Why is this?

Given the answer to this question, I don't think this is too broad; the answer is mostly the same nationwide because of a federal law that restricts the fees airports can charge passengers as part of their airfare, to just $4.50 (as opposed to, say, Heathrow's nearly $52)

Comment: Because the US is the home of capitalism?

Comment: I've seen that occasionally in Europe as well. In Germany, I would even say that it is quite common. Some times you only have to pay a deposit, which you get back if you return the luggage cart to any of the collection points.

Comment: In the US, even in international arrivals, it becomes common that you need to pay with a credit card. It used to be free just because people usually don't have the required change/bills yet, but with credit cards now....

Comment: Airports that allow free usage seem to have well-constructed barriers so that's impossible to take the carts beyond certain points. US airports generally don't have this type of setup. So, let them loose, and they're going to remain in the far reaches of the parking lots/structures or otherwise become 'lost'.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I've also seen a model here in the States where you get refunded a portion of your cart usage fee if you return the cart properly.

Comment: @mkennedy Or cheap labor to put the carts back

Comment: In the UK I never use a luggage trolley/cart as they seem to be for a fee only. (At least in some of the airports.) I have to add that I usually have so little luggage that I can do without one.

Comment: @Willeke You don't usually check bags? (I find carts quite convenient as a family of four, traveling with 8 checked suitcases, 4 carry-on suitcases, and 4 personal items.)

Comment: I mostly travel alone, by public transport and try to keep to one piece of luggage (with wheels if heavier) and at most one bag besides (personal item size.) I do use the hand luggage carts within Schiphol (AMS) for my hand luggage but those things do not seem to exist in the UK.

Comment: @Willeke Never heard of hand luggage carts; how do those look like?

Comment: https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/handbagage-op-kar-luchthaven-3653875.jpg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Luggage carts in the USA are provided by a company called [Smarte Carte](https://www.smartecarte.com/). While the exact contract details are confidential, the airport lets Smarte Carte operate in return for a portion of the rental fees. Sometimes the carts are free in some areas such as international arrivals but for-pay in other areas.

If you really don’t want to pay, hang out around the taxi stand at the arrivals area and a departing customer will often give you one. Same goes for parking lots.

In other more civilized countries, luggage carts are seen as a basic amenity such as toilets and air conditioning and provided free of charge.

**The economics of airports:**

As @user71659 notes, this may be due to the economics of airports in the USA versus other countries. In the USA, [passenger facility charges are capped to $4.50 per passenger](https://www.faa.gov/airports/pfc/), so the airports themselves may provide few amenities and may be poorly staffed. Other countries allow for much higher landing fees which allow for more amenities to be “free”.

For example, Tokyo Narita airport provides free carts and their [passenger fee  is ¥2630 per person](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/faq_ask/psfc), which is about US$25. Narita explicitly notes that its passenger fee is "used to cover the cost of maintaining and managing the lobbies...[and] to provide baggage carts...." (per comment from @user71659).

In contrast, San Francisco (SFO) charges for its Smarte Cartes in the domestic terminals and its passenger fee is the max US$4.50.

Comment: Aren't free luggage carts often available in European countries where pay toilets are fairly common, while pay toilets are quite rare (and sometimes illegal) in the US?

Comment: "Civilized" countries have much higher airport passenger fees ($52 per head at LHR vs. a FAA limit of $4.50, though there are other fees like landing and slots), so you've paid for those "free" carts whether you use them or not.

Comment: @user71659 are you sure? I pulled landing fees for sfo and nrt and they don’t jive with your assertion. It might be cherry picking though.

Comment: @RoboKaren You didn't look at [passenger fees](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/faq_ask/psfc). Comparable landing fees, which usually apply to cargo operations in addition to passenger, but a higher passenger fee supports my point exactly.

Comment: @user71659 got it. I can’t find the equivalent charge on the sfo side.

Comment: @RoboKaren It's capped at [$4.50](https://www.faa.gov/airports/pfc/) nationwide.

Comment: @user71659 found it right after you responded. Thx.

Comment: Also in the [Narita link](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/faq_ask/psfc), it explicitly calls out the carts: "PSFC is used to cover the cost of maintaining and managing the lobbies... It is also used to provide baggage carts...."

Comment: I hailed a taxi from a U.S. airport with a luggage cart in hand, and the taxi driver set the cart on its side just beside the stand before we took off.

Comment: I think the low passenger facility charge is partly why commercial ownership of airports has mostly failed, and all but one of our airports are publicly owned: the charge is too low to make a profit, while publicly-owned airports can overcome the deficit with taxpayer money.

Comment: @gparyani That's not true, airports, especially large ones, are profit generators for the owners, e.g. [SFO](http://media.flysfo.com.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/investor/FY17AOB.pdf) turned an annual profit of $44M (Annual Service Payment). Like roadways, some infrastructure is paid for by a fuel and ticket excise tax that is collected federally, then returned back to the airports in grants. The lack of private airports is due to a belief that they are for the public good, like roadways.

Comment: I'd also push back on the idea that US airports "provide few amenities and may be poorly staffed" compared to European airports. Some are awful in their own ways, but does SFO really lack large numbers of amenities and staff that are offered at, say, LHR or FRA? Free luggage carts are an example (they are available free to arriving international passengers at SFO, but not all US airports do this), but what other amenities do US airports not have?

Comment: @Zach Pay toilets are indeed increasingly common in Europe, but not inside airports. I have yet to encounter the first one.